# Adding pointers to chars

Tags: c, pointers, mingw, addition

I suspect when for reasons of portability adding pointers is making underlying assumptions regarding the implementation, but can someone please explain why under MinGW GCC I am unable to do the following, due to the following error

> "invalid operands to binary `+` (have `char *` and `char *`)"

```
char *cbase;
char *ep;
char *tbase;
tbase = ep + tbase;
```

Yet, if I manipulate the code slightly I can get away with

```
char *cbase;
char *ep;
int temp;

temp = cbase;
tbase = ep + temp;
```

I know that I am making some assumptions regarding the pointer implementation but my point is why can't the compiler resolve it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You cannot *add* two pointers.

Pointer(s) is(are) memory address(es). Just think for a moment, even if *you would have been* allowed to *add* two pointers, what is the significance of the result? It will produce *mostly* an *invalid* value, isn't it?

OTOH, you can add an `int` to a pointer. It is like generating an address by *moving* that many elements.

Moreover, from the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.6, *Additive operators* (*emphasis mine*)

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is
>   equivalent to adding 1.)**

Comment: Thankyou.   I am porting an old Small C application so it appears that the standards have moved along a bit since the 80's.  Arguably I am achieving what I want by using and int to hold the address - but I understand the standard now.

Comment: Yes your point regarding the invalid nature of the code is correct.  The original author was using pointers as unsigned integers due to the limitations if the small c compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Adding two pointers would most likely generate and invalid pointer and hence it's not allowed, but adding an integer to a pointer is perfectly valid, it will increment the pointer, i.e. the resulting pointer will very likely be valid, unless you add a value that makes it point outside of the memory block it originally pointed to.

You cannot add pointers, but you can compute pointer differences, they will be like distances for example

```
char *source = "Some text for a test";
char *head = strstr(source, "text");
char *tail = strstr(source, "for");
size_t length = tail - head - 1;
```

will give you the length of `text`, so you can calculate pointer differences.

Comment: Thanks iharob - that is clever.  I can use that and it will solve my problem.

Comment: @Alan there is even a special type for pointer differences `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: I can't stray too much from the small C language unless I add library functions as I need to compile the compiler, but I would like to stay close to the standards, hence the purpose of porting to MinGW GCC first.

Comment: For that, you can work in a nicer environment for a programmer like **Linux** use *gcc* with `-std=c11` or whatever standard you want to stick to.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  Thanks